# redistributing application with NAG math libraries- client must have license?

Tags: c, math, numerical

Has anyone dealt with re-distributing an application that uses the Numerical Algorithms Group (NAG) Libraries?

It seems like when I build an executable, it won't run unless I have an environment variable set for the license file- i.e. if I gave someone the code they would need a license and associated daemon as well.

Is there no way around that? I was hoping I only need the license to link with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pkarasev,
You didn't say much about the nature of the application or what kind of organization. If you work for an academic institution and the application is to be shared with other researchers on a non-commercial basis, we have a program that may allow you to distribute it on a no-cost basis for users. Even if your application is to be sold, we can make so that you don't have to use NAG's license management in the application.

If you've got more questions and just want to talk with someone call either me or or John Holden in our Oxford UK office (+44 1865 511245)
Rob Meyer
+1 630 598-5215

Comment: Great, thanks. Yes it is at an institute, for sharing with other researchers non-commercially. Anyone in this university can install the libraries/license manager, it would be easier if I could just give someone a .so or .dll; someone elsewhere would be harder as it stands.

I see this link: http://www.nag.co.uk/educationuk/academicprogram.asp ; so I should contact you through the address there or via phone regarding redistributable libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Many parts of NAG are available for free with permissive licenses. For example, NAG's linear algebra package is taken from LAPACK, which is available in a BSD style license. You might be able to track down free versions of every sub-package in NAG, but it just won't be bundled up as nicely, and you'll then have to figure out how to make them all work together. If you list what functionality you use, perhaps people can offer more suggestions.

Comment: Specifically root-finding, sparse linear solver, and nonlinear optimization with and without equality/inequality constraints. I was under the impression that NAG linked with MKL should give higher performance than the BSD style lapack/blas (which I have too).   

But I'm not sure if my question went across- for example, if I want to ship something with MFC, I need a license for visual studio, but the user does NOT. It seems with NAG that the *user* must have a NAG license, is that correct?

Comment: @pkarasev: I believe that is correct; any machines which run NAG software must have a license. It is stated in their standard product license.

For sparse linear solves, I use TAUCS or PETsC. For root-finding and nonlinear optimization, the NAG manual usually describes the underlying algorithm, so you might be able to find a more free version.